# Properties of intersection of subalgebras

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative $k$-algebra, which is an integral domain, where $k$ is a field of characteristic zero.
Let $R_i$, $i \in \mathbb{N}$, be $k$-subalgebras of $R$. Denote $A:=\cap_{i \in \mathbb{N}}R_i$. Trivially, $A$ is a $k$-subalgebra of each $R_i$ and of $R$.

> I am interested in a list of 'good' properties $P$ such that if each of $R_i$ satisfies property $P$, then $A$ also satisfies property $P$.

Examples for such good properties $P$:
**(1)** Normality (integral closedness in its field of fractions).
**(2)** UFD.

Additional properties that I am interested in, but I do not know if they are 'good': beign Noetherian, being Artinian.

> What if, in addition, $R_i$ is a descending chain, namely, if $i < j$, then $R_i \supseteq R_j$.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but if $R_i$ is a descending chain than isn't every property  that followed by every such R  trivially "goes to" A as well?

Comment: It depends on the property, I think. For example, the property "Krull dimension two" is a counterexample: If $R_i:=k[x^{2^i},y^{2^i}]$, $i \in \mathbb{N}$, then $A=k$, which is of Krull dimension zero.

Comment: Ok, yes thank .

Comment: I guess that there are properties that work for the descending chain case, but not for the more general case, perhaps being Noetherian? (BTW, I confess that at first sight it was tempting to think as you thought).